# Can we pass information to Marketing Cloud API's without creating a corresponding field in a Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I have a Journey configured in Marketing Cloud with an Entry Point set as a Data Extension. All the journey does for the moment is send an email. In the email, I have 5 dynamic/personalised strings. Out of these 5, I would like to capture only 3 strings in the Entry level DE. However, when I try to 'Activate' the journey, I get an error saying that the Email could not be 'Verified'. Once I remove the extra 2 personalised strings (that are not part of the DE), the Journey Activates successfully. How can I achieve this use case? :)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your email uses fields in the Data Extension that are not part of your Journey you could either do a lookup to a separate data extension for those extra fields, that way your email will validate, or you could add an extra field to your DE that can have a JSON string that then you can parse using Guide template language.

Comment: thanks @patosapir! I think I'll simplify the context by removing Journeys. My basic requirement is to include 5 personalised strings in an email (triggered from the API) but have the Data extension include only 3 of them. The Lookup won't work because the information is being passed by the API itself. But I like the GTL suggestion! So basically we include an additional field in the DE, pass the other 2 fields' info into the JSON string and write to this field, and then break down this JSON into 2 separate fields in the email using GTL?! Hope I got it right. :)